# OSGi getServiceReference returning null

Tags: java, null, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle

I am new to the Java OSGi framework. I am following an example tutorial here : https://o7planning.org/en/10135/java-osgi-tutorial-for-beginners

I have a MathService bundle which provides basic math functions and a MathConsumer bundle which uses the MathService bundle. The packages are properly exported from the MathService bundle and dependencies properly set for the MathConsumer bundle.

The context.getServiceReference call in the MathConsumer Activator is returning null for some reason, causing an exception and I can't understand why. Below are my files. Would anyone have experience with this?

MathConsumer Activator.java :

```
package org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi.mathconsumer;

import org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi.mathservice.MathService;
import org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi.utils.MathUtils;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
    return context;
    }

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;
        System.out.println("MathConsumer Starting...");

        System.out.println("5-3 = " + MathUtils.minus(5, 3));

        //
        ServiceReference<?> serviceReference=context.getServiceReference(MathService.class);

        if (serviceReference == null) {
           System.out.println("serviceReference is null"); // THE PROBLEM IS HERE 
        }

        MathService service = (MathService)context.getService(serviceReference);

        if (service == null) {
        System.out.println("MathService service is null");
        }

        System.out.println("Got Mathservice service");

        System.out.println("5+3 = " + service.sum(5, 3));

        System.out.println("MathConsumer Started");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;
        System.out.println("MathConsumer Stopped");
    }

}
```

MathService Activator.java

```
package org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi;

import org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi.mathservice.MathService;
import org.o7planning.tutorial.helloosgi.mathservice.impl.MathServiceImpl;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

   private static BundleContext context;

   static BundleContext getContext() {
       return context;
   }

   public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
       Activator.context = bundleContext;

       System.out.println("Registry Service MathService...");

       this.registryMathService();

       System.out.println("OSGi MathService Started");
   }

   private void registryMathService() {
       MathService service = new MathServiceImpl();
       context.registerService(MathService.class, service, null);
   }

   public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
       Activator.context = null;
       System.out.println("OSGi MathService Stopped!");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is an ancient one. I strongly recommend to forget about it.

The code has a number of issues, the biggest ones being:

- the code is executed only once at bundle startup. That defeats the purpose of having services.
- there is no guarantee that `MathService` will start before `MathConsumer` therefore it is perfectly fine that the service is not available (null) at the time it's being requested.

If you absolutely need to do this in the activators, then you should look at [ServiceTracker](https://osgi.org/javadoc/osgi.core/7.0.0/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) and call the service from a thread that can wait for the service to be registered without blocking the activator.

But there is much easier way to do that with [Declarative Services](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html) [using annotations](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-annotations).

If you are just trying to learn OSGi, I recommend to start with [enRoute](https://enroute.osgi.org/).

Comment: Thanks for that information. I think that the tutorial gave me a good start to understand how things work together in the framework anyways. Are there other newer OSGi tutorials that you would recommend?

Comment: Follow @NewsOsgi on twitter - tons of links there.